How to find nested object that occurs the most by given parameters?
I have the following data in my elasticsearch tenders index:
{
        "_index": "tenders",
        "_id": "204cda9e9f1541758a6e7be03c296185",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "tenderId": "204cda9e9f1541758a6e7be03c296185",
          "status": "complete",
          "title": "Цвяхи - 80, Цвяхи - 100",
          "publicTenderId": "UA-2023-12-15-017779-a",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "e063998b195545ce851b6827ed358905",
              "classification": {
                "scheme": "ДК021",
                "cpv": "44530000-4"
              }
            },
            {
              "id": "8b6325cf93d94bb59bbf575950ffc372",
              "classification": {
                "scheme": "ДК021",
                "cpv": "44530000-4"
              }
            }
          ],
          "value": {
            "amount": 210,
            "currency": "UAH"
          },
          "suppliers": [
            {
              "contractId": "5a65a7e538e64c6297cf20e0995f0a2a",
              "contractAwardId": "151a9da56d334984b4b686ca7be175bf",
              "name": "ФОП Кузьменко Костянтин Андрійович",
              "identifier": {
                "scheme": "UA-EDR",
                "id": "2096015130"
              }
            }
          ],
          "procuringEntity": {
            "name": "ВІДДІЛ З ГУМАНІТАРНИХ ПИТАНЬ ОВРУЦЬКОЇ МІСЬКОЇ РАДИ",
            "organization_id": "41818470",
            "organization_scheme": "UA-EDR",
            "address": {
              "streetAddress": "ВУЛИЦЯ ТАРАСА ШЕВЧЕНКА, БУДИНОК 31А",
              "locality": "Овруч",
              "region": "Житомирська область",
              "postalCode": "11101",
              "countryName": "Україна"
            }
          },
          "date": "2023-12-15T16:03:31.067236+02:00",
          "dateCreated": "2023-12-15T16:01:22.096013+02:00",
          "dateModified": "2023-12-15T16:03:31.067236+02:00",
          "contracts": [
            {
              "dateSigned": "2023-12-15T09:00:00+02:00"
            }
          ],
          "indexedAt": "2024-07-03T03:42:40.355Z"
        }
      }

Now I need to find top-3 procuringEntity with the following conditions:

at least one item in _source.items.classification.cpv matches the one provided by user
procuring entities must be sorted by

cumulated cost of active tenders (can be determined by _source.value.amount) DESC
number of active tenders (can be determined by _source.status) DESC



Or in other words, I need to find top-3 procuring entities that have the most active tenders and the biggest overall amount.
I've written the following query
this.elasticSearchService.search({
      index: TENDER_INDEX_NAME,
      query: {
        bool: {
          filter: [
            {
              term: {
                'items.classification.cpv.keyword': cpvCode,
              },
            },
            {
              term: {
                'status.keyword': 'active',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      aggregations: {
        active_tenders: {
          filter: {
            term: {
              status: 'active',
            },
          },
        },
        active_tenders_count: {
          value_count: {
            field: 'status.keyword',
          },
        },
        total_value: {
          sum: {
            field: 'value.amount',
          },
        },
      },
    });

Now I'm not sure what kind of result I am getting. There's a list of tenders where CPV code matches the one I provided, but I don't see anything related to active tenders amount or cumulated cost of all tenders. What do I need to do to get the list of procuring entities with additional properties active_tenders_amount and cumulated_cost? Do I need to create another index with procuring entities and a list of tenders to be able to do so?
